# HTML5 file upload script not loading file

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

Newbie to the HTML5 file upload capability, and finding I cant get a simple xml file uploaded and able to get file contents into console. The expected behaviour is that I'd select an xml file and then see the contents rendered in console. However, I dont ever get to the console.log step - seems the reader never loads?  Any suggestions to resolve would be most appreciated.

```
<input type="file"></input>
   <script>
 var upload = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]; 
    upload.onchange = function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var file = upload.files[0], reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (event) {
      console.log('evt',reader.readAsText(file));
      };


  return false;
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're setting the `reader.onload` event to a function, but you need to call the `reader.readAsText()` function outside of this.

So for example change your code to:

```
reader.onload = function(event) {
  console.log(event);
};
reader.readAsText(file);
```

What this does is to tell the `reader` that when you call `reader.readAsText(file)` it should run the function you defined with `reader.onload`.

What you were doing before would never load the file because you were only telling the reader to `readAsText` inside your function callback that you told it to run when it was already loaded!

Comment: Hah! my extensive js skills coming to the fore. Thanks Mike for your very prompt assistance. I was looking at it but just couldnt see it, if that makes sense...